# Heroku gunicorn absence

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

Trying to upload my Django app to Heroku and getting:

```
2013-05-22T23:04:55.687398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn main.wsgi`
2013-05-22T23:04:56.508882+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2013-05-22T23:04:57.958215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-05-22T23:04:57.941729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-05-22T23:05:06.019313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-05-22T23:05:06.019520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

I know gunicorn is in requirements.txt and have pushed that so it should all work. The app runs with foreman.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was accidentally pushing a .bash_profile which had got in my project and was setting the PATH causing havoc on the heroku stack.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, Heroku's buildpacks just fail in completely strange ways.

Try this:

```
 heroku run pip install gunicorn
```

See what happens.

Comment: Thanks. That raises `bash: pip: command not found`. And according to this http://bit.ly/13NxljQ it's not clear that it would work anyway. I also tried it with `heroku run bash` which gave me a bash terminal. Not sure what next..

Comment: OK, then you don't have the right build pack. Type heroku config and let me know what the BUILDPACK_URL is.

Comment: I did that and it returns no BUILDPACK_URL. I only get DATABASE_URL and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL which are both postgres:// prefixed URLs. Thanks.

Comment: OK, if it's not finding pip, it doesn't think it's a Python app, for whatever reason. Run `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python`, do a commit in your repo and a push.

Answer (score 0):

I just did what Jack Shedd said, and it works fine for me.

Run:

```
herouku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

Then, do a commit in your repository. Finally, do:

```
git push heroku master
```